# Crawling Data Using python

Tags: python, selenium

hy guys, i want to import mechanize in python program, when i run the output is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eSTO.png)
i try to follow to install with this text : pip install mechanize and already installed it. and i try to install python setup.py install from this https://github.com/abielr/mechanize and still the same error.
But when i run again, it's still the same error. any body can help me please?
i'm using windows 10 anyway.
Thanks

Comment: post the code please

Comment: Are you running it in a virtualenv?

Comment: i run from Spyder and command prompt